# How to configure sharepoint timer job to run multiple times a day?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

How can I configure a sharepoint timer job to run multiple times a day.

For example: Daily between the intervals 14:00-16:00 and 20:00-24:00

I want to do it using SharePoint object model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create 2 instances, each one running at its own slot once a day